# Can you have dyanmic (spreadable) attrubutes in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to construct an element's attributes from an object?

For example I have the object `var options = {name: 'book', class: 'red', id='book1'}`.

Can I then use this variable in the following way:

```
<a {...options}>foo bar baz</a>
```

And it will render the following code:
    foo bar baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the object syntax with `v-bind`. Documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).

```
<a v-bind="{name: 'book', class: 'red', id:'book1'}">foo bar baz</a>
```

Comment: can one of those options be v-model?

Comment: @TheOne no. That’s a different directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can add object inside the data and use that options object in your html:

```
data: {
  optionsAttributes: {
     'id': 'someProp',
     'other-attr': 'otherProp'
  }
}

<a v-bind="optionsAttributes">foo bar baz</a>
```

---

Adding styles:

```
data: {
  optionsStyles: {
     'color': 'blue',
     'font-size': '20px'
  }
}

<a v-bind:style="optionsStyles">foo bar baz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [JSX](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx), try this:

```
render(h) {
  const attributes= {
    attrs: {name: 'book', class: 'red', id: 'book1'},
    on: {}
  }

  return <div {...attributes}></div>
  // result: <div name='book' class='red' id='book1'></div>
}
```

The attributes accepts: `domProps`, `attrs`, `on`, `nativeOn` and `hook`.